# delete multiple files on linux with spaces in file names

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a directory on my Linux box with over 10000 files that I have to delete.  Running...

```
sudo rm -rf /var/tmp/*
```

Gives the error message...

```
sudo: unable to execute /bin/rm: Argument list too long
```

The solution to this is to run

```
sudo find /var/tmp | xargs sudo rm
```

This only works for files with no spaces in the file name.  However, some of the files have names with spaces in them and they are not deleted.  For example, if a file is named 'A File With Spaces in the Name.dat', Running the command gives me errors like this....

```
rm: cannot remove `/var/tmp/A': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `File': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `With': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `Spaces': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `in': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `the': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `Name.dat': No such file or directory
```

How do I pass the complete file path to xargs sudo rm without breaking up the file name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tell `find` and `xargs` to use a different file separator:

```
find /var/tmp -print0 | sudo xargs -0 rm
```

Or tell `find` to execute `rm` directly:

```
sudo find /var/tmp -exec rm {} +
```

Or tell `find` to just delete the files:

```
sudo find /var/tmp -delete
```

Note: `-mindepth 1` might be useful, to avoid deleting the `/var/tmp` directory itself.

...or really, just drop the `*`, it's not necessary if you were going to use recursive mode in the first place.

```
sudo rm -rf /var/tmp
```

Comment: @raido: Note the update.

Comment: Just a detail. Avoid do `sudo rm`, it will be much slower if you got to execute `sudo` before each `rm`. Run the command in a root console instead.

Comment: @criziot: It shouldn't be much slower, since `xargs` and the `-exec +` form will execute `rm` only once for a whole ton of files. One could still change it to `sudo xargs` and `sudo find` to avoid the problem.

Comment: @grawity: I didn't notice the `-exec +` form. In fact I was not even aware that it exists. But you're obviously right. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the previous answer to avoid problem with deleting directories:

`find /var/tmp -type f -exec sudo rm {} +`

`find /var/tmp -depth -type d -exec sudo rmdir {} +`

`rmdir -p` can also be used for removing all descendant of a directory instead of using -depth.